# Same "Where" each time returns different result

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have a .NET service (using Entity Framework 6.0.0-rc-1)

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    protected DbConnection _connection = new DbConnection();

    public HttpResponseMessage MyProcedure1()
    {
        ...
        var dayPlans = _connection.DayPlans
                          .Where(dp => dp.period >= start && dp.period < end);
        if (dayPlans.Count() > 0)
        {
            //success
        }
        else
        {
            //fail
        }
        ...
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage MyProcedure2()
    {
        ...
        var dayPlans = _connection.DayPlans
                          .Where(dp => dp.period >= start && dp.period < end);
        if (dayPlans.Count() > 0)
        {
            //success
        }
        else
        {
            //fail
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

These procedures being used simultaneously by client side. The thing is from time to time dayPlans.Count() equals zero while it should not. I've double checked filtration params and database content, there are few records that has to be selected from db, but they are not.

Another important moment is when LINQ request in one method fails, it always fails in another. But when these procedures are called one after another they might fail in all possible variants - first request failed, second succeeded; first failed second failed; etc.

What might be the problem?

Comment: You've shown two methods which do exactly the same thing - why? Also note that using `Any()` is clearer than using `Count() > 0` and can be more efficient in some scenarios.

Comment: What is `DbConnection`? Is it data context?

Comment: Where are `start` and `end` being set?

Comment: 1) They don't do same thing, it's just initial data is common.
2) `DbConnection` is `DbContext`
3) `start` and `end` are set above.
`var now = DateTime.Now;
            var start = now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second));
            var end = now.AddDays(1).Subtract(new TimeSpan(now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second));`

Answer (score 0):

That was my mistake, date boundaries weren't calculated correctly